# Passing Values from (DataGridView1_Click) in a Form to another sub in another form

Tags: vb.net, forms

I want to pass value from (DataGridView1_Click) to another sub which is in another form
How To Achieve that?
Is there any way to do that, Please help me

```
Public Class SearchCustomers
Private Sub SearchCustomers_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtCustomerSearchBox.Text = ""
        CBCustomerSearch.SelectedIndex = -1
        txtCustomerSearchBox_TextChanged(Nothing, Nothing)
    End Sub
```

This the click Event

```
  '  Private Sub DataGridView1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Click
  'FrmCustomers mycustomers = New FrmCustomers()   
  '  mycustomers.show_data(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString)
  '  End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_RowsAdded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowsAdded
        For I = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            DataGridView1.Rows(I).Cells(0).Value = "Go"
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(I)
            row.Height = 25
        Next
    End Sub
```

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick( ByVal sender As System.Object,  ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

     End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_Click( ByVal sender As System.Object,  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Click
            Dim oForm As New FrmCustomers()
            Dim CustomerCode As String
            CustomerCode = (DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString)
            oForm.show_data(CustomerCode)
            MsgBox(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Warning Message")        
End Sub
End Class
```

this is the sub method in form 2
I want from this method to show data from DB to TextBox as seen in the code below

```
 Sub show_data(CustomerCod)
        OpenFileDialog1.FileName = ""
        Dim sqls = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerCode=N'" & (CustomerCod) & "'"
        Dim adp As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqls, SQLconn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        adp.Fill(ds)
        Dim dt = ds.Tables(0)
        If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("no record found", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "warning message")
        Else
            Dim dr = dt.Rows(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            CustomerCode.Text = dr!CustomerCode
            CustomerName.Text = dr!CustomerName
            Address.Text = dr!Address
            Country.Text = dr!Country
            City.Text = dr!City
            Fax.Text = dr!Fax
            Mobile.Text = dr!Mobile
            Email.Text = dr!Email
            Facebook.Text = dr!Facebook
            Note.Text = dr!Note
            '====================== Image Reincyrpation 
            If IsDBNull(dr!Cust_image) = False Then
                Dim imgByteArray() As Byte
                imgByteArray = CType(dr!Cust_image, Byte())
                Dim stream As New MemoryStream(imgByteArray)
                Dim bmp As New Bitmap(stream)
                Cust_image.Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
                stream.Close()
                Label16.Visible = False
                '================================================
            End If
            BtnEdit.Enabled = False
            BtnDelete.Enabled = False
            BtnSave.BackColor = Color.Red
            CustomerName.Focus()
            End If 
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use the default `FrmCustomers` instead of creating a new instance of it

Comment: you mean like this `Private Sub DataGridView1_Click( ByVal sender As System.Object,  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Click
            FrmCustomers.show_data(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString)
            MsgBox(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Info Message")        
End Sub` it does not work

Comment: Is `FrmCustomers` open already? If so, how did you open it? It should be `FrmCustomers.Show ()` - still using the default.

Comment: You would also have to declare `Sub show_data ()` as `Public`.

Comment: There is A button in FrmCustomers to Open SearchCustomers Form and I declare `Sub show_data ()`  as `public`still the same issue, in the end, I put the GridView inside FrmCustomers , it works perfectly ... Thank U ^____^

Comment: How would you know if it works perfectly when you have `On Error Resume Next`. Please take that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this (just to Call):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Click
    FrmCustomers.Show()
    FrmCustomers.Hide()
    FrmCustomers.show_data(CustomerCod)
    FrmCustomers.Dispose()
End Sub
```